# Android sharedPreferences using a Preference to work like a button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using sharedpreferences framework, but I'm having a little trouble interacting with one of the preferences. I want to enable one of my options to reset my app. To do this I want a dialog box to appear on screen with an OK and  Cancel. If the user then clicks OK I want to do a bunch of stuff.

I can write all this in a normal activity using a ImageView listener. but in the SharedPreferences framework I dont know how to add the listener and actions. I guess as an added bonus, I would also be required to interact with the current SharedPreferences states too?

at the moment I have this XML

```
<PreferenceCategory  android:title="Reset App">

    <Preference
        android:title="Reset App?"
        android:summary="Click here to reset the App to defaults."
        android:key="resetapp" />

</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory  android:title="General Settings">
 <CheckBoxPreference
         android:title="Enable Sounds?"
         android:defaultValue="true"
         android:summary="A Tick here will enable sounds throughout body-mix-ology."
         android:key="enablesounds" />
 <CheckBoxPreference
         android:title="High performance Phone?"
         android:defaultValue="false"
         android:summary="If you have a high performance phone tick here to speed up body switching."
         android:key="highperformancephone" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
```

and this is my class file

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

        //TODO
        // act on resetapp
        // prompt onscreen confirmation.

    }

    public AlertDialog createDialog() {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Reset App?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure? You will wipe all data from the app.")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "App has been reset!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //TODO
                // clear DB
                // reset sharedprefs.
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "App was not reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        })
        .show();

   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about having a ListPreference with "Are you sure you want to do this?" and list values "Yes" and "No" with default "No". Then respond to any "Yes" confirmation like this:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    if (key.equals("resetapp") && prefs.getString(key,"").equals("Yes")) {
        // reset the value to "No" so that next time a preference change will be triggered
        prefs.edit().putString(key, "No").commit();

        // now do your awesome reset stuff ...
        Preference someOtherPref = findPreference(otherKey);
        ...
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change your class definition to:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
```

and register the eventlistener:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```